# Is there any reason not to use Single-Key EM with AES and a constant key?

Tags: aes, key-reuse

I've read recently the paper ["Minimalism in Cryptography: The
Even-Mansour Scheme Revisited" by Dunkelman, Keller and Shamir](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/541.pdf) where it is claimed that the following construction (Single-Key EM) is secure:

$$C=K\oplus E(P\oplus K)$$

with $E$ being a publicly known fixed permutation.

**Is there any reason not to use the above scheme (as block cipher) with AES-128 and key $0^{128}$ as $E$?**

As for the reasons why somebody may want to use it:

- It can provide smaller implementations, enabling the hard-coding of the round constants
- It may be faster for the same reason
- It is more key-agile, allowing for much faster key switches (e.g. in a hashing / [KFB](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30180/23623) scenario)

Comment: I guess that you might rather want to refer to the algorithm as Single-Key EM in the title as well. XTS seems to have some additional properties that are not included in this scheme (and is treated as a mode of encryption rather than a block cipher).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, fixed. Note that XTS $\neq$ XEX $\neq$ Single-Key EM as XTS uses two keys, XEX is XTS with one key and Single-Key EM is the here described scheme.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is considered in §6 of [Bogdanov et al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/035), who go on to devise an alternative 2-round AES-based Even-Mansour cipher—$\text{AES}^2$. The problem is, essentially, that 1-round Even-Mansour is only secure up to $2^{n/2}$ blockcipher queries, for an $n$-bit block. Specifically, a collision between $\text{SEM}_K(P) \oplus P$ and $E(P) \oplus P$ immediately reveals $K$ (cf. §4.2 of [Dunkelman-Keller-Shamir](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/541)).

In general, you want an Even-Mansour cipher targeting $n$-bit security to have block size $2n$. This is the case with, e.g., Salsa20 and ChaCha's core functions, which are Even-Mansour-like, target 256-bit security, and work on 512-bit blocks. Several permutation-based [CAESAR](http://competitions.cr.yp.to/caesar-submissions.html) candidates, such as [Prøst](http://proest.compute.dtu.dk/) or [Minalpher](http://info.isl.ntt.co.jp/crypt/minalpher/index.html), work similarly.

Comment: Very good answer! Great resources, good job!