# Security of Even-Mansour scheme with keyed shuffle?

Tags: algorithm-design

I was researching the [Even-Mansour scheme](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/541.pdf) and had a question that wasn't addressed in the paper that I saw, and google was minimally helpful.

What if a permutation that uses secret data like the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) was used as the F permutation instead of a publicly known one? Would the scheme still be equivalently secure?

I noticed the section in the paper that if F is an involution the security proof no longer holds. So there appear to be certain restrictions, and I'm not sure if this idea would violate them.

Comment: I think I may have misinterpreted the meaning of "permutation" in this context (again...). I was thinking of permutation in the sense of a shuffling of bytes among the block, as opposed to a permutation among all possible blocks, [like aes in this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30221/29554)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand the Even-Mansour security result, it helps to first understand the [random oracle model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle).  Roughly speaking, the random oracle model says that a hash function should behave like a randomly chosen function, and have no detectable patterns or structural properties that a random function wouldn't have.  Of course, the hash function is publicly known, so anyone can compute it, but apart from that, it shouldn't have any other structural properties.

Even-Mansour uses something similar, but now for permutations.  The requirement in the Even-Mansour proof is that $F$ is a random permutation oracle: it has to behave just like a randomly chosen permutation (random bijective function), and have no detectable structural properties that a random permutation wouldn't have.  Of course, $F$ can be publicly known (so given $x$ anyone can compute $F(x)$ and $F^{-1}(x)$), but apart from that, it shouldn't have any other structural properties.

This is like an unkeyed version of the [ideal cipher model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle#Ideal_cipher).  See [What is the ideal cipher model?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10347/351).

Once you understand the ideal cipher model, you can then evaluate whether some specific construction would qualify.  It basically comes down to whether your other construction qualifies as a reasonable instantiation of a random permutation oracle (i.e., as a reasonable instantiation of an unkeyed version of an ideal cipher).

Fisher-Yates is not suitable except for constructing block cipher, as the running time of Fisher-Yates is super exponential: if you want a random permutation on $b$ bits, the running time of Fisher-Yates is at least $(2^b)!$, which grows asymptotically as something like $2^{(b-1.44) \cdot 2^b}$... i.e., huge.

Comment: Minor correction: $F$ is an ideal *permutation* not ideal *cipher*, with the distinction being that an ideal permutation is keyless (it takes a single argument) while an ideal cipher takes two arguments, one of them interpreted as a key. The goal of Even-Mansour is to make a keyed primitive (cipher) from a keyless one (ideal permutation)..

Comment: @Mikero, oops, right on!  Thanks for the correct.  I edited to fix that.  Thanks again!