# Regarding XEX mode

Tags: encryption, modes-of-operation, pseudo-random-permutation, disk-encryption

Wikipedia [claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor%E2%80%93encrypt%E2%80%93xor) that given an unkeyed permutation $p$ (presumably of the same size as the key) this is safe: $p(m \oplus k) \oplus k$
Why isn't this construction used instead of XEX? Surely unkeyed permutations should be faster than keyed ones since they do not have a key schedule, is there some issue not mentioned by the wikipedia page?

It also raises the question, given a block cipher $e$, would $e_{k_1}(m \oplus k_2)$ (without the outer xor) be safe? My interest is specifically about full-disk encryption.

Comment: This seems to be about Orr Dunkelman, Nathan Keller, and Adi Shamir. "Minimalism in Cryptography: The Even–Mansour Scheme Revisited". In how far does [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/30221/1172) answer your question?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I think that it fully answers the first part of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why isn't this construction used instead of XEX?

Because [XEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor%E2%80%93encrypt%E2%80%93xor) takes a block cipher and constructs a *tweakable block cipher* out of it, whereas this construction, usually called Even-Mansour, takes a permutation and constructs a block cipher out of it.

> Surely unkeyed permutations should be faster than keyed ones since they do not have a key schedule, is there some issue not mentioned by the wikipedia page?

This is a difficult question. This is because security models are way harder to construct for unkeyed permutations than for keyed ones - because you don't have a knowledge advantage over the adversary. Because of this lack of an advantage, public permutations tend to be slower in fact, e.g. the fastest one I know is [Gimli which is still beaten by AES](https://gimli.cr.yp.to/perf.html). Also note that the key-schedule is a one time cost and usually can be amortized quite well if you don't change the key often - which normally you don't do.

In fact this speed disadvantage is theoretically expected given that we can construct block ciphers from the most minimal cryptographic primitive - One Way Functions but cannot construct collision-resistant hash functions froms them which we can from publicly secure permutations. So there's something "intrinsic" that makes public permutations a stronger tool than block ciphers and this usually mean we have to do more computational work to construct it.

> It also raises the question, given a block cipher e, would ek1(m⊕k2) (without the outer xor) be safe?

Yes, it would yield another block cipher (a [PRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation) assuming the block cipher is a PRP itself) with a longer key. Though note that it does not yield a SPRP (a PRP where the inverse is also a PRP). If you were to take the $k_2$ as a tweak, I don't think this would yield a (strong) tweakable block cipher unlike XEX due to a lack of preprocessing of the tweak which may be non-random.

Comment: Aren't block ciphers with a publicly known constant key just unkeyed permutations? Is there a benefit from having a SPRP? As for Gimli, as far as I know that it is made for constrained systems, wouldn't chachacore be a faster permutation?

Comment: @BobSemple Block ciphers are designed to only provide security for unknown keys. They are technically allowed to fail horribly if the key is known (e.g. define a block cipher where the key is always a fixed-point, you can't guess the key so as long you don't know the key it's secure). Some constructions require SPRPs instead of PRPs (eg OCB). ChaCha core is a pseudo-random function from what I understand, that is it's not reversible.

Comment: Apologies, I meant the internal chacha permutation. chachacore is just $p(x) \boxplus x$.