# Why doesn't ChaCha use a 512bit key and xor parameters into it?

Tags: permutation, chacha, tweakable-cipher

ChaCha has clear delineations between key, nonce, counter and constants.

What is the reason for not using a XEX-like ($k=0$) approach such that the ChaCha key is 512 bits and all the other things are XOR'ed with the key, and only the key is XOR'ed with the ChaCha permutation output?

ChaCha already has some similarity to Even-Mansour with the way it is constructed, why not go all the way? Currently, it only does partial single key Even-Mansour with partially known key, known plaintext and partially exposed ciphertext.[1]

Attacker doesn't gain any additional control over the input he did not have before, and the security of the cipher when the attacker is passive becomes $2^{512}$.

Are there any downsides?

[1]
If ChaCha is an Even-Mansour-like construction then:

- half of the key is effectively 0
- constants, counter, nonce are all known, rest of the plaintext is 0

Comment: 256 bits of security is enough againts for all adversaries, classical and quantum. The biggest problem with ChaCha is the short nonce size. To increase the none size XChaCha20 wad developed ; Xchacha20 extends the nonce of ChaCha20 without changing the function of ChaCha20. The aim of Xchacha20 is to extend the 128-bit nonce size of ChaCha20 to 192-bit in order to generate random nonces to use safely in the long-lived keys without the fear of the nonce-collision.

Comment: 256 may be enough, but my question is why not have 512. is there any downside?

Comment: 256 maybe enough for who, 512 may be enough for who? ChaCha has 512-bit block size, you need to consider this, too, since you will get 768 key size. XEX was started to increase the key size of DES, then with Rogaway's tweak it is used for disk encryption ( well modified to XTS) so people are content with AES-256m, there. So, why do you need 512-bit key size?

Comment: I believe Even-Mansour security is limited to half of block size. Also ChaCha requires constants to break symmetry.

Comment: constants can be xored into the key, and they are there under the assumption that someone will choose a very stupid symmetric key & nonce. if that occurs you really have bigger problems.

Comment: @LoraineToorla That would make subset of keys that would be weak (xoring constants to key would just move it to different values). Also since counter would also effectively change key, I would hardly consider it 512-key. It would effectively approach 256-bit key security with increasing output due to birthday paradox (key-nonce/counter would start to collide).

Comment: @LightBit sure, but that is a problem with Even-Mansour as well. when not under active attack you do gain the full 512 bits of security, do you not?

Comment: @LoraineToorla You get full 512 bits only if you output only single block with every key. If you output 2 blocks you lose 1 bit of security, because counter/key will collide with another counter/key. Similarly nonce/key combinations will collide. Even-Mansour is supposed to be used with double block size (if you want 512-bit security, use 1024-bit permutation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious downside is there would be $2^{256}$ weak inputs (key-nonce-counter) due to ChaCha requiring constants to break symmetry ([see this paper at 3.1 about NORX permutation based on ChaCha](https://tosc.iacr.org/index.php/ToSC/article/view/589)) and collisions between key and nonce/counter which are expected in Even-Mansour, but not in ChaCha. It is also unknown if ChaCha permutation is free of differential and linear characteristics with complexity lower than $2^{512}$.

There is little to no upside since [Even-Mansour is considered secure up to $2^{n/2}$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30353/8069).

As to why it is not designed to have 512-bit key. It is because it is considered unnecessary.

Using Keccak permutation would be better. It is 1600-bit and has round constants that break symmetries internally. It could provide 800-bit security in Even-Mansour and plenty of nonce/counter bits. I would still recommend concatenating input like ChaCha instead of xoring them together, as it is waste of insane 1600-bit key that looses strength with number of blocks generated.